# Troubles for fit this floating table to the page

Tags: tables, floats, tabularx

Sorry for the question but I have the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true,]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}  
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}   
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}      
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} c|ccccccY @{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Fórmulas de conversión}\\
\midrule
        & $K=$ & $E=$ & $\lambda=$ & $G=$ & $\nu=$ & $M=$ & Notas \\
($K,E$) & $K$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{3K(3K-E)}{9K-E}$ & $\dfrac{3KE}{9K-E}$ & $\dfrac{3K-E}{6K}$ & $\dfrac{3K(3K+E)}{9K-E}$ & \\
($K,\lambda$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9K(K-\lambda)}{3K-\lambda}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{3(K-\lambda)}{2}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{3K-\lambda}$ & $3K-2\lambda$ & \\
($K,G$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9KG}{3K+G}$ & $K - \dfrac{2G}{3}$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{3K-2G}{2(3K+G)}$ & $K + \dfrac{4G}{3}$ & \\
($K,\nu$) & $K$ & $3K(1-2\nu)$ & $\dfrac{3K\nu}{1+\nu}$ & $\dfrac{3K(1-2\nu)}{2(1+\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{3K(1-\nu)}{1+\nu}$ & \\
($K,M$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9K(M-K)}{3K+M}$ & $\dfrac{3K-M}{2}$ & $\dfrac{3(M-K)}{4}$ & $\dfrac{3K-M}{3K+M}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($E,\lambda$) & $\dfrac{E+3\lambda +R}{6}$ & $E$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{E-3\lambda +R}{4}$ & $\dfrac{2\lambda}{E+\lambda +R}$ & $\dfrac{E-\lambda +R}{2}$ & $R = \sqrt{E^2 + 9\lambda^2+2E\lambda}$ \\
($E,G$) & $\dfrac{EG}{3(3G-E)}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{G(E-2G)}{3G-E}$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{E}{2G}-1$ & $\dfrac{G(4G-E)}{3G-E}$ & \\
($E,\nu$) & $\dfrac{E}{3(1-2\nu)}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{E\nu}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$ & $\dfrac{E}{2(1+\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{E(1-\nu)}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$ & \\
($E,M$) & $\dfrac{3M-E+S}{6}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{M-E+S}{4}$ & $\dfrac{3M+E-S}{8}$ & $\dfrac{E-M+S}{4M}$ & $M$ & $S=\pm\sqrt{E^2 + 9M^2 - 10EM}$ Hay dos soluciones válidas: El signo más da $\nu\geq0$. El signo menos da $\nu\leq0$.\\
\midrule
($\lambda,G$) & $\lambda + \dfrac{2G}{3}$ & $\dfrac{G(3\lambda+2G)}{\lambda+G}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{2(\lambda+G)}$ & $\lambda + 2G$ & \\
($\lambda,\nu$) & $\dfrac{\lambda(1+\nu)}{3\nu}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}{\nu}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1-2\nu)}{2\nu}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1-\nu)}{\nu}$ & \\
($\lambda,M$) & $\dfrac{M+2\lambda}{3}$ & $\dfrac{(M-\lambda)(M+2\lambda)}{M+\lambda}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{M-\lambda}{2}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{M+\lambda}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($G,\nu$) & $\dfrac{2G(1+\nu)}{3(1-2\nu)}$ & $2G(1+\nu)$ & $\dfrac{2G\nu}{1-2\nu}$ & $G$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{2G(1+\nu)}{1-2\nu}$ & \\
($G,M$) & $M - \dfrac{4G}{3}$ & $\dfrac{G(3M-4G)}{M-G}$ & $M-2G$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{M-2G}{2M-2G}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($\nu,M$) & $\dfrac{M(1+\nu)}{3(1-\nu)}$ & $\dfrac{M(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}{1-\nu}$ & $\dfrac{M\nu}{1-\nu}$ & $\dfrac{M(1-2\nu)}{2(1-\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $M$ & \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\caption[Módulos elásticos]{Los materiales elásticos lineales isotrópicos homogéneos tienen sus propiedades elásticas determinada únicamente por cualesquiera dos de los módulos entre sí; por tanto, dados cualesquiera de los dos, cualquier otro de los módulos elásticos se puede calcular de acuerdo con estas fórmulas.}
\label{taula:elastmod}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

As you can see the table is big and doesn't fit at the page, that's the main problem, but another one is about the distance between rows. In actually all the rows, I use mathematical expressions that include fractions created with `\dfrac` and the distance between rows is very small and the fractions almost clash between them.

How could I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the best I can think of for such a hige table. First reduce the `\tabcolsep` to, say `3pt`. Then use a `landscape` page and reduce the font size to `\footnotesize` (change as suitable). To add some gap between rows use `cellspace` package and use `Sc` instead of `c` column. But it is still big (Sigh)

```
\documentclass[fontsize=10pt,paper=letter,headings=big,bibliography=totoc,DIV=9,headsepline=true,]{scrbook}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,x11names,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[spanish,mexico]{babel}
\usepackage[intlimits]{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,empheq,bm}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage[spanish=mexican]{csquotes}
\usepackage{xspace}
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{array,multirow,tabularx,ragged2e,booktabs}
\newcolumntype{Y}{>{\RaggedRight\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
%
\usepackage{cellspace}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{2pt}      %% change as you wish
\setlength\cellspacebottomlimit{2pt}   %% change as you wish
\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}
\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}
\centering
\rowcolors{2}{}{lightgray!20}
\begin{tabularx}{1.02\linewidth}{@{\kern\tabcolsep} Sc|ScScScScScScY @{\kern\tabcolsep}}
\toprule
\multicolumn{8}{c}{Fórmulas de conversión}\\
\midrule
        & $K=$ & $E=$ & $\lambda=$ & $G=$ & $\nu=$ & $M=$ & Notas \\
($K,E$) & $K$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{3K(3K-E)}{9K-E}$ & $\dfrac{3KE}{9K-E}$ & $\dfrac{3K-E}{6K}$ & $\dfrac{3K(3K+E)}{9K-E}$ & \\
($K,\lambda$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9K(K-\lambda)}{3K-\lambda}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{3(K-\lambda)}{2}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{3K-\lambda}$ & $3K-2\lambda$ & \\
($K,G$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9KG}{3K+G}$ & $K - \dfrac{2G}{3}$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{3K-2G}{2(3K+G)}$ & $K + \dfrac{4G}{3}$ & \\
($K,\nu$) & $K$ & $3K(1-2\nu)$ & $\dfrac{3K\nu}{1+\nu}$ & $\dfrac{3K(1-2\nu)}{2(1+\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{3K(1-\nu)}{1+\nu}$ & \\
($K,M$) & $K$ & $\dfrac{9K(M-K)}{3K+M}$ & $\dfrac{3K-M}{2}$ & $\dfrac{3(M-K)}{4}$ & $\dfrac{3K-M}{3K+M}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($E,\lambda$) & $\dfrac{E+3\lambda +R}{6}$ & $E$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{E-3\lambda +R}{4}$ & $\dfrac{2\lambda}{E+\lambda +R}$ & $\dfrac{E-\lambda +R}{2}$ & $R = \sqrt{E^2 + 9\lambda^2+2E\lambda}$ \\
($E,G$) & $\dfrac{EG}{3(3G-E)}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{G(E-2G)}{3G-E}$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{E}{2G}-1$ & $\dfrac{G(4G-E)}{3G-E}$ & \\
($E,\nu$) & $\dfrac{E}{3(1-2\nu)}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{E\nu}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$ & $\dfrac{E}{2(1+\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{E(1-\nu)}{(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}$ & \\
($E,M$) & $\dfrac{3M-E+S}{6}$ & $E$ & $\dfrac{M-E+S}{4}$ & $\dfrac{3M+E-S}{8}$ & $\dfrac{E-M+S}{4M}$ & $M$ & $S=\pm\sqrt{E^2 + 9M^2 - 10EM}$ Hay dos soluciones válidas: El signo más da $\nu\geq0$. El signo menos da $\nu\leq0$.\\
\midrule
($\lambda,G$) & $\lambda + \dfrac{2G}{3}$ & $\dfrac{G(3\lambda+2G)}{\lambda+G}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{2(\lambda+G)}$ & $\lambda + 2G$ & \\
($\lambda,\nu$) & $\dfrac{\lambda(1+\nu)}{3\nu}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}{\nu}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1-2\nu)}{2\nu}$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{\lambda(1-\nu)}{\nu}$ & \\
($\lambda,M$) & $\dfrac{M+2\lambda}{3}$ & $\dfrac{(M-\lambda)(M+2\lambda)}{M+\lambda}$ & $\lambda$ & $\dfrac{M-\lambda}{2}$ & $\dfrac{\lambda}{M+\lambda}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($G,\nu$) & $\dfrac{2G(1+\nu)}{3(1-2\nu)}$ & $2G(1+\nu)$ & $\dfrac{2G\nu}{1-2\nu}$ & $G$ & $\nu$ & $\dfrac{2G(1+\nu)}{1-2\nu}$ & \\
($G,M$) & $M - \dfrac{4G}{3}$ & $\dfrac{G(3M-4G)}{M-G}$ & $M-2G$ & $G$ & $\dfrac{M-2G}{2M-2G}$ & $M$ & \\
\midrule
($\nu,M$) & $\dfrac{M(1+\nu)}{3(1-\nu)}$ & $\dfrac{M(1+\nu)(1-2\nu)}{1-\nu}$ & $\dfrac{M\nu}{1-\nu}$ & $\dfrac{M(1-2\nu)}{2(1-\nu)}$ & $\nu$ & $M$ & \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabularx}
\caption[Módulos elásticos]{Los materiales elásticos lineales isotrópicos homogéneos tienen sus propiedades elásticas determinada únicamente por cualesquiera dos de los módulos entre sí; por tanto, dados cualesquiera de los dos, cualquier otro de los módulos elásticos se puede calcular de acuerdo con estas fórmulas.}
\label{taula:elastmod}
\end{table}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

[image]

I suppose this table is pushing every thing to the limits, and you may consider splitting the large table in to smaller tables or use `longtable`. Sorry and my sympathies.

Comment: Thanks for your effort and the suggestions, Perhaps `longtable` could be the best choice, now my trouble is how to _translate_ the table to `longtable` . Another issue I found when I added the new packages suggested in the answer to my project is an error that says `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\ecolumn): `c' used. \end{tabularx}` and other one with `siunitx`: `Package array Error: Illegal pream-token (\__siunitx_table_collect_begin:NnS{table-format=4.4}): `c' used. \end{tabularx}` and `Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup. \end{tabularx}`.

Comment: @Aradnix You can try `makecell` package instead of `cellspace` or simply re define array strech like `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}`

Comment: I tried to use the `\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.2}` in the preamble, but the error still remains. I was searching about the  `pdflscape` package that require the packages `lscape` and `atbegshi` but I'm not sure if the package load them automatically or not.

Comment: @Aradnix May be you have some package that is conflicting. Delete packages one by one and see if the error vanishes.